# How do we use Memory in conversational chain in order to pass the previous chats to the agent

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

i am building a python agent like this :

```
 template = """
    History :{history} "\n" 
    Human: {human_input}  "\n" 
    AI Assistent :""" 
 PROMPT = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["history" ,"human_input"], template=template)

 llm = OpenAI(model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo')

 memory = ConversationSummaryMemory(llm=llm)
    
 conversation_chain = ConversationChain(
     prompt=PROMPT,
     llm=llm,
     verbose=True,
     memory=memory
   )
 output = conversation_chain.predict(input=human_input)
 return output
```

and using this code in fast api but whenever i try to call this API using string  it generates following error .

```
  Got unexpected prompt input variables. The prompt expects ['history', 'human_input'], but got ['history'] as inputs from memory, and input as the normal input key. (type=value_error)
```

there is an open issue in github regarding this so can anyone help me to find the workaround for this ??